# Vagrant 1.2.2 Not Running Puppet Manifest

Tags: apache, vagrant, puppet

The vm resulting from `vagrant up` seems to work fine.  But I can't seem to get vagrant to add apache (the webserver) to it, in the simplest of configurations. I'm using Puppet.

I've made sure to `vagrant destroy` and then `vagrant up`.  Upon `vagrant ssh`, apache isn't there (no apachectl, no httpd).

Details below:

Environment:

```
bash-3.2$ vagrant --version
Vagrant version 1.2.2
bash-3.2$ uname -a
Darwin foo.com 12.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.3.0: Sun Jan  6 22:37:10 PST 2013; root:xnu-2050.22.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
bash-3.2$ 
bash-3.2$ pwd
/Users/bar/cbalz
bash-3.2$ ls -ail
total 24
1500058 drwxr-xr-x   7 bar  staff   238 Aug  6 16:27 .
 379691 drwxr-xr-x+ 37 bar  staff  1258 Aug  6 11:29 ..
1500065 drwxr-xr-x   3 bar  staff   102 Aug  6 11:23 .vagrant
1500631 -rw-r--r--   1 bar  staff  4948 Aug  6 16:25 Vagrantfile
1500619 -rw-r--r--   1 bar  staff    33 Aug  6 13:34 index.html
1500107 drwxr-xr-x   3 bar  staff   102 Aug  6 16:28 manifests
1500704 drwxr-xr-x   2 bar  staff    68 Aug  6 14:24 www
bash-3.2$ 

foo:cbalz bar$ ls -ail manifests
total 8
1500107 drwxr-xr-x  3 bar  staff  102 Aug  6 16:28 .
1500058 drwxr-xr-x  7 bar  staff  238 Aug  6 16:27 ..
1500806 -rw-r--r--  1 bar  staff  405 Aug  6 16:28 precise64.pp
foo:cbalz bar$
```

Vagrantfile :

```
foo:cbalz bar$ more Vagrantfile
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
# ...
config.vm.box = "precise64"
# ...
# Customization:
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise64"

  # Enable the Puppet provisioner
  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
     puppet.manifests_path = "/Users/bar/cbalz/manifests"
     puppet.manifest_file  = "precise64.pp"
     puppet.options = "--verbose --debug"
  end
end
# ...
end
```

Puppet Manifest File:

```
foo:cbalz bar$ cat manifests/precise64.app 
# Basic Puppet Apache manifest

class apache {
  exec { 'apt-get update':
    command => '/usr/bin/apt-get update'
  }

  package { "apache2":
    ensure => present,
  }

  service { "apache2":
    ensure => running,
    require => Package["apache2"],
  }
  # ...
 }
```

Set-up:

```
$ vagrant destroy; vagrant up
Are you sure you want to destroy the 'default' VM? [y/N] y
[default] Forcing shutdown of VM...
[default] Destroying VM and associated drives...
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Importing base box 'precise64'...
[default] Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
[default] Setting the name of the VM...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2203.
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2203 (adapter 1)
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes.
[default] VM booted and ready for use!
[default] Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
[default] Mounting shared folders...
[default] -- /vagrant
```

Run:

```
$ vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-23-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Welcome to your Vagrant-built virtual machine.
Last login: Fri Sep 14 06:23:18 2012 from 10.0.2.2
;vagrant@precise64:~$ apachectl
The program 'apachectl' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install apache2.2-common
vagrant@precise64:~$ httpd
No command 'httpd' found, did you mean:
 Command 'xttpd' from package 'xtide' (universe)
httpd: command not found
vagrant@precise64:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing

Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise64"

from the Vagrantfile so that the configuration looks like below:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
# ...
  config.vm.box = "precise64"

  # Enable the Puppet provisioner
  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "/Users/bar/cbalz/manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "precise64.pp"
    puppet.options = "--verbose --debug"
  end
# ...
end
```

Comment: Works perfectly with your clean fix.  It turns out I was following [outdated docs](http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/getting-started/provisioning.html) .